# How to support Rails recyclable cache keys for non-Active Record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What methods need to be defined for a non-Active Record object to support cache versioning (i.e. recyclable cache keys) in Rails? Do only `cache_key` and `cache_version` need to be defined, or does `cache_key_with_version` also need to be defined?

For example, is this sufficient?

```
class Car
  def cache_key
    "cars/someid"
  end

  def cache_version
    "sometimestamp"
  end
end
```

Then in some view:

```
<% cache @car do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Or does `cache_key_with_version` also need to be defined?

```
class Car
  def cache_key_with_version
    "#{cache_key}-#{cache_version}"
  end
end
```

I dug around the Rails codebase for about an hour, but the answer is still unclear to me. I haven't been able to test via trial and error since I'm not sure how to confirm whether cache keys are actually being recycled (I'm using memcached).

Thanks!